# Button sometimes doesn't work..is there a better way?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So i have a save and load function in this game, (its built on ionic so i had to copy out the code that was specific to this inquiry as i couldn't find a place to post all my code from all the different ionic files.)

in this jsfiddle you can see the basics of what the buttons do and the variables i'm storing and using,

http://jsfiddle.net/ay6afgLn/

the problem is sometimes they just don't work, or the span displays 0 until you buy one, and sometimes clicking reload fixes it, other times it doesn't.. it's really inconsistent. I am using onload="load" on each page to auto load each time you change tab and that works 50% of the time?

it seems to work fine on the jsfiddle, but not in my game.

when i have 20 different variables and it's running the save command every second and then anytime you press a button i have the button run "document.getElementById("milk").innerHTML = prettify(milk);" only for whatever value has been changed, is there a better way to do all this or am i trying to load way too much? or am i saving too often?

```js
var cash = localStorage.getItem("cash") ? localStorage.getItem("cash") : 0.0;
var milk = localStorage.getItem("milk") ?  localStorage.getItem("milk") : 0.0;
var milkShakes = localStorage.getItem("milkShakes") ?  localStorage.getItem("milkShakes") : 0;
var iceCreams = localStorage.getItem("iceCreams") ?  localStorage.getItem("iceCreams") : 0;
var MSmilkCost = localStorage.getItem("MSmilkCost") ?  localStorage.getItem("MSmilkCost") : 2;
var ICmilkCost = localStorage.getItem("ICmilkCost") ?  localStorage.getItem("ICmilkCost") : 5;
var milkRate = localStorage.getItem("milkRate") ?  localStorage.getItem("milkRate") : 1.0;

function prettify(input){
    var output = Math.round(input * 1000000)/1000000;
  return output;
}




$("#milkButton").click(function(e) {

    
    milk += milkRate;
   
    document.getElementById("milk").innerHTML = prettify(milk);
    
});


$( document ).ready(function() {
    

  $("#milkShakeBuy").click(function(e) {

    if (milk >= MSmilkCost){

      milk -= MSmilkCost;
      milkShakes = milkShakes += 1;
      
      document.getElementById("milk").innerHTML = prettify(milk);
      document.getElementById("milkShakes").innerHTML = prettify(milkShakes);
      
      
      
    }
    else{
      pass;
    }
      
  });
});  


$("#iceCreamBuy").click(function(e) {

  if (milk >= ICmilkCost){

    milk -= ICmilkCost;
    iceCreams = iceCreams += 1;
      
    document.getElementById("milk").innerHTML = prettify(milk);
    document.getElementById("iceCreams").innerHTML = prettify(iceCreams);
    
    
  }
  else{
    pass;
  }
    
    
});











function save(){

  var save = {

    milk: milk,
    cash: cash,
    iceCreams: iceCreams,
    milkShakes: milkShakes,
  }
  localStorage.setItem("save",JSON.stringify(save));
};


function load(){
    var savegame = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("save"));
    milk = savegame.milk;
    cash = savegame.cash;
    milkShakes = savegame.milkShakes; 
    iceCreams = savegame.iceCreams;
    document.getElementById('milk').innerHTML = milk;
    document.getElementById('cash').innerHTML = cash;
    document.getElementById('milkShakes').innerHTML = milkShakes;
    document.getElementById('iceCreams').innerHTML = iceCreams;
};

window.setInterval(function(){
  save();
  document.getElementById('milk').innerHTML = milk;
  document.getElementById('cash').innerHTML = cash;

  
    
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div class = "row">
    <div id = "stats"> Milk = <span class = "stat" id = "milk">0.0 <br /> </span></div>
    <div id = "stats">Cash = $<span id = "cash" >0.0</span></div>
          
</div>
<div class = "col" ><button id = "milkButton"class="button">Milk The Cow</button></div>
 

<p>Buy MIlkShake for <span id ="MSmilkCost">0</span>Milk</p>
<button class="button" id = "milkShakeBuy">Buy</button>
<br />
<p>Buy Ice Cream for <span id ="ICmilkCost">0</span>Milk</p>
<button class="button" id = "iceCreamBuy">Buy</button>
```

Comment: Side note: Code like `var cash = localStorage.getItem("cash") ? localStorage.getItem("cash") : 0.0;` can be simply written as `var cash = localStorage.getItem("cash") || 0.0;` If the left expression is undefined, it will use the value on the right.

Comment: Another side-note: If you are going to use jQuery at all, use it throughout. Your code will be a lot shorter/simpler. e.g. `document.getElementById("milk").innerHTML = prettify(milk);` becomes `$('#milk').html(milk);`

Comment: feel free to comment on anything else i could do better, i tried storing dictionaries instead of individually hardcoding which was awesome for displaying all items but not for trying to have a customised button on each individual list item/ another awesome tip thanks...

Comment: Rather than use all those separate variables, just use a single instance of a `save game` object to hold them all. That removes half the code shown straight away.

Comment: Another note: `pass;` is not a valid Javascript command.

Comment: Sorry, you are right

Comment: Here is a somewhat cleaned-up version of your code: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/ay6afgLn/1/ note: This is not the way I would write such a project, but it may give you some ideas on improvements to your code. If you can clarify the exact problem in that version I will see what I can do to help :)

Comment: Another note: You have a number of lines like this: `milkShakes = milkShakes += 1;` that should just use increment: `milkShakes++` (or worst case the long-hand `milkShakes = milkShakes + 1;`).

Comment: OK awesome thanks heaps guys, How would you do such a project? 

Thanks for showing the shortened code, @TrueBlueAussie but i have a question, I see you make all the variables into one called game now? but you still have to have them all listed individually to save the data? so whats the point of having the game variable? could't i just go save game?

Comment: I will change all the code to the shortened jqeury and hopefully that fixes my issue, I will report back if it is still doing it.

Comment: I did not want to save the additional parts you were not currently saving, but by all means save and load the `game` object instead. (If you do want me to write the whole thing it's £60 an hour) :)

Comment: Haha if i could afford you i would :P maybe one day :P Oh ok, i just added in the last thing but in my full version i have around 20-30 variables (with more to come) and nearly all will be changing as the game progress so will need to be saved...

Comment: So put them all in the single object and load/save that. The pattern does not change.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Awesome! Thanks, I was planning to switch to localforage would that be the same? as i need it to work well on android and ios and was worried the 5mb limit of localstorage would prevent it?

Comment: Only save what you need to in a `game` state and put static settings in another object (`options`?).

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie ok no problems, question.. if i may. I'm converting it all to jquery and i was wondering about the load game function, How do i just load "game"? I have all the variables i need to save inside of "game" and now how do i load it? also where do you reccomend putting onload="load()" so it auto loads?

Comment: Re load. I do not understand. The `load()` example provided does that. `document.ready` (or the shorter `$(function(){});` is your starting point for the app. No need for `onload=`.

Comment: Sorry to be clearer, is there a way to just say load game without defining each individual variable inside of game and setting it. Thanks for taking the time to answer.

Comment: The game settings are just an object. The values declared at the start are just defaults. The only thing that might break (if they do not exist first) would be an increment. Best for documentation purposes to have the named elements present so you can reference them. Personally I would use a high-level language like TypeScript so that you can use interface declarations and string typing (but that's just me) :)

Comment: I haven;t heard of typescsript but i will look it up, is that compatible with ionic?

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie I tried to update most of it to jqeury and now my buttons aren't working at all. can you see anything immediately wrong? http://jsfiddle.net/a2ujjbxc/1/

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie So i finally get it working with all jquery code and the same issue happens, without onload=load() the numbers just reset to 0 when the page reloads.. and when i go from the first tab to the second tab and try to buy milkshakes too half the time it doesn't work so i click reload then build up the milk again then wait 5 seconds before clicking buy and then it works.. so seems to not work half the time and the page is loaded so it shouldn't need to wait until the page is loaded..